# MS SQL How Attach a duplicate database

Tags: sql

I only have a single Microsoft SQL server, i have a database lets call it DB1, I recovered the DB1.mfd and DB1_log.ldf file and saved it in a different location on the same server. Now when i try to attach the recovered DB I get "Cannot attach a database with the same name as an existing database. "

I don't want to take down or shut DB1 down just so i can attach an old recovered version to copy some entries. I tried to change the physical file name (e.g. DB2) but when attaching the db file, SQL still see it as DB1.

How do i attach this DB or change the Database name without taking down DB1 that is currently running.

Answer (score 1):

Considered changing the name? Maybe not done in the UI (really no idea for that), but worst case https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-attach-db-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16 shows you the exact documentation for the sp_attach_db stored procedure, which allows changing the name of the attached db on the server side.

Comment: ultimately i attached the old DB to another SQL Server, so that the DB doesn't need to be shutdown.
I guess what i was hoping for was a way to change the name of a database that isn't attached so that i can attach it without conflicting with the current DB that is being used.